Multiple regex replaces for 1 column
I have a case I need to replace multiple substrings within 1 column using PostgreSQL.
Example:



Region
City




Moscow obl
Istra


Rep Bashkortostan
Ufa


Udmurtskaya Rep
Izhevsk



I need all substrings 'obl' to be replaced with 'oblast' and 'Rep' replaced with 'Republic'
I tried to use subquery like
select regexp_replace
                     ((select regexp_replace(
                                             wt.region_with_type,
                                             '\sobl$','oblast') 
                                             from work_table wt),        
                      '^Rep\s|\sRep$','Republic') as project_f_region
                       from work_table wt

But it throws an error
postgresql error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
I tried to google the answer, but couldn't find any solutions.
I know I can use CTE, but as for me the query gets too bulky
Is there any other way to use multiple replaces with different substrings?

You can use multiple regex_replace functions :
SELECT regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace(
              wt.region_with_type, 
              '\sobl$', 
              'oblast'
          ), 
          '^Rep\s|\sRep$', 
          'Republic'
      ) AS project_f_region
FROM work_table wt


u mean without subqueries, function over function, don't u?

No need to use subqueries; a simple nested regexp_replace can do the trick

I suggest using CASE.
select
case
  when regexp_like(wt.region_with_type, '\sobl$') then regexp_replace(wt.region_with_type,'\sobl$','oblast')
  when regexp_like(wt.region_with_type, '^Rep\s|\sRep$') then regexp_replace(wt.region_with_type,'^Rep\s|\sRep$','Republic')
  else wt.region_with_type
end as substitution
from work_table wt


well, nice solution, didn't get it by myself, thank you)

@NickZakharov you can show your appreciation by accepting my answer, or up-voting it (or both :-)

You can nest function calls directly, without mixing in subqueries. Simply
select f(f(x)) from work_table;

in contrast to your
select f(select f(x) from work_table);

which would only work if you had a single row in your work_table. I'm wondering if it wasn't just a typo, a lost or misplaced closing parenthesis ) and you actually tried
select f(select f(x)) from work_table;

Or, in full: demo at db<>fiddle
select regexp_replace(
           (select regexp_replace( wt.region_with_type
                                  ,'(\s)obl$'
                                  ,'\1oblast'
                   )
           )--this ends the inner select that doesn't have a `from`, just a single value
          ,'^Rep(\s)|(\s)Rep$'
          ,'\2Republic\1'
       )
from work_table wt;

Which technically uses an entirely correct scalar subquery, but that is just syntax noise you don't really need. It would have the exact same result as
select regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace( wt.region_with_type
                          ,'(\s)obl$'
                          ,'\1oblast'
           )
          ,'^Rep(\s)|(\s)Rep$'
          ,'\2Republic\1'
       )
from work_table wt;

Note that you probably need to correct your replacement patterns like I did above, so that you don't wipe the whitespace \s characters you included in the search pattern.
